# Create table Athena ignore comma in the row values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am creating a table in Athena using below scripts

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `itcfmetadata`(
  `itcf id` string, 
  `itcf control name` string, 
  `itcf control description` string, 
  `itcf process` string, 
  `standard` string, 
  `controlid` string, 
  `threshold` string, 
  `status` string, 
  `date reported` string, 
  `remediation (accs specific)` string, 
  `aws account id` string, 
  `aws resource id` string, 
  `aws account owner` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION
  's3://itcfmetadata/'
TBLPROPERTIES (  
  'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

The S3 source file is csv file. This file is converted from a excel file and this csv file doe snot have comma seperated values, it is more like a excel file.  Problem is when any column contains text like "Hi, How are you". It get split into two as there is a comma and "Hi" and "How are you" becomes two value and get split into two rows. How to avoid this using above create scripts ?

CSV File :

[image]

Comment: Do you have control over how the excel files are exported to CSV? You will need to properly quote the comma inside the cell value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
```

instead of `DELIMITED`

The `DELIMITED` deserializer just looks at the delimiters you provide. The csv deserializet will only use those outside a pair of double quotes `"`.

See the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html